# Switch case of object in PHP

Tags: php, json, if-statement, laravel-5, switch-statement

I don't have a good knowledge in PHP. Will you please, anyone help me to implement a switch case or if else statement in a set of objects.

For example I have set of JSON object like below

```
 {"car":[{"colour":"black", "brand":"BMW", "owner":"rob"}]}
 {"bike":[{"colour":"red",  "brand":"Bajaj", "owner":"john"}]}
 {"cycle":[{"colour":"blue",  "brand":"Hero", "owner":"mike"}]}
```

My requirement is need to check it's car, bike or cycle.
in the below example message is the random JSON object

```
$smsobj = json_decode($message, true);
switch ($smsobj) {
    case $smsobj->bike:
      $this->bike($smsobj);
      break;
    case $smsobj->car:
      $this->car($smsobj);
      break;
    case $smsobj->cycle:
      $this->cycle($smsobj);
      break;
      default: $resolver->acknowledge($message);
  }
```

when I received a car object I will get some error like this `Trying to get property 'bike' of non-object`

Thank you.

Comment: `defualt` < you made a typo there. That should read as "default".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP Switch statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739516/php-switch-statement)

Answer (score 1):

Use `json_decode($message);` instead of `json_decode($message, true);`

When passing `true` as a second argument to `json_decode`, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.

If you want to use it as an associative array, you can access it like so: `$smsobj['bike'];`

By the way, the code will probably not run as you expect. `$smsobj` will never be equal to one of its properties. You probably want to check if the key exists instead.

You can even avoid using `switch`/`case` or `if`s, and do something like that:

```
$smsobj = json_decode($message);

$key = array_key_first($smsobj); // PHP >= 7.3

$method = method_exists($this, $key) ? $key : 'acknowledge';

$resolver->$method($message);
```

If you run a lower version of PHP (< 7.3) you can find a polyfill in the docs:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-first.php